# Multiple DB connections in ZF3

Tags: database, zend-framework3

When I was using ZF1, I had an ini file with db connection information (i.e. mysql, pgsql, mssql, etc...)

```
modulename.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
modulename.params.host = xxx.xxx.x.xx
modulename.params.username = username
modulename.params.password = password
modulename.params.dbname = databasename
```

and in my model, I would extends Zend_Db_Table and do the following in my

```
public function _construct() {
        $dbconfig = Zend_Registry::get('dbProfiles');
        $this->db = Zend_Db::factory($dbconfig->modulename->adapter,
        $dbconfig->modulename->params);         
}
```

in some function, I have the following code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
$result = $this->db->query($sql);
while($row =$result->fetch()) {
//... do something
}
```

How can I do something similar to this in ZF3?  Connecting multiple database types, querying different tables, and fetching my results?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your configuration set as many database adapters as you have databases:

```
    'db'    => [
    'adapters'  => [
        'Application\Db\Db1Adapter'   => [
            'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
            'Dsn'   => 'mysql:dbname=Your_db_1_name;host=your_host;charset=utf8',
            'password' => 'your_password',
            'username' => 'your_username',

        ],

        'Application\Db\Db2Adapter' => [
            'driver'    => 'Pdo_Mysql',
            'Dsn'       =>  'mysql:dbname=Your_db_2_name;host=your_host;charset=utf8',
            'password' => 'your_password',
            'username' => 'your_username',


        ]
    ]
],
```

Then call the adapter in service manager factories to create tablegateway or just pass the adapter to the controller:

```
use \Application\Db\Db1Adapter;
...
    $db1Adapter = $container->get(Db1Adapter::class);
    ...
```